# MVC 3 MS Ajax Browser History

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Кто может подсказать, в чём может быть проблема? Сейчас попробую описать проблему:
Сделал постраничный вывод новостей посредством аякса. Хочу добавить browser history для удобства. Целиком переписывать код, как у меня формируются страницы, не буду, ибо много кода. Да и не нужно всё. Напишу самое основное: Имеются `Ajax ActionLink` хелперы (ссылки листания страниц `[1,2,3,4,...]`): `PageNum` - номер текущей страницы.

```
Ajax.ActionLink("4", "NewsPages", new { pageNum = pageNum + 1 }, new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "newsDiv", OnBegin = "onBegin", OnComplete = "onComplete"}, new {rel = pageNum + 1 })
```

И имеется JavaScript для обработки событий:

```
<script type=""text/javascript"">
    var _currentPageNum = -1;

    Sys.Application.add_init(page_init);

    function page_init() {
        Sys.Application.set_enableHistory(true);
        Sys.Application.add_navigate(navigate);
    }

    function navigate(sender, e) {
        var pageNum = e.get_state().pageNum;
        if (pageNum != _currentPageNum) {
            _currentPageNum = pageNum;
            $("#NewsDiv").load("?pageNum=" + pageNum);
        }
    }

    function onBegin() {                            
        _currentPageNum = this.getAttribute("rel"); // тут проблема.
        Sys.Application.addHistoryPoint({ "pageNum": _currentPageNum });
        $("#NewsDiv").fadeOut(500);
    }

    function onComplete() {
        $("#NewsDiv").fadeIn(500);
    }
</script>
```

Так. Далее. JS Библиотеки, которые я подключаю:

```
jquery-1.6.4.min.js  
jquery.tools.min.js  
MicrosoftAjax.js  
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js  
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
```

Вроде бы всё. Теперь собственно вопрос: Клик по ссылке вызывает функцию onBegin, а затем onComplete, и естественно переходит на нужную страницу. Но это как и должно быть. Но есть некая проблема:
**this.getAttribute("rel");** - эта строка по идее, должна мне вернуть значение **rel** ссылки, по которой я только что кликнул. Но проблема в том, что при наличии ЭТОЙ строки, у меня перестаёт срабатывать код.

Comment: попробуйте в ActionLink здесь:
<pre>..new {rel = pageNum + 1 }...</pre>
записать
<pre>..new {rel = (pageNum + 1).ToString() }...</pre>
возможно он хочет, чтобы все ``htmlAttributes`` были строковыми

Comment: Дело, к сожалению, не в этом.  
Если убрать строку `_currentPageNum = this.getAttribute("rel")`, то всё сразу начинает работать. Но для корректной навигации мне эта строка ОЧЕНЬ нужна. Или каким ещё методом можно вытащить значение `rel` из текущей ссылки? )

Comment: Кстати, а почему вы для этого не используете метод ``jQuery $(this).attr('rel');``

И вопрос, в самой html страничке этот атрибут присутствует?

Comment: Да, присутствует.
$(this).attr('rel'); //возвращает undefined

Comment: По-моему, тогда проблема в ``this``, но я не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Пока что решил вопрос посредством добавления ссылкам имени класса `navlink` и дописал дополнительную функцию:

```
$(".navlink").click(function () { 
    _currentPageNum = $(this).attr("rel"); 
});
```